# error: cannot find symbol MultiFormatWriter, BitMatrix, BarcodeEncoder, WriterException

Tags: android, qr-code, zxing

I am trying to use zxing library for qrcode.
gradle-wrapper.properties:

```
#Sun Dec 13 19:31:11 IST 2020
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.5-all.zip
```

build.gradle file:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.swuljcityconductor"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.3.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.zxing:core:3.2.1'
    implementation 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.2.0@aar'
}
```

qrcode code:

```
MultiFormatWriter multiFormatWriter = new MultiFormatWriter();
        try {
            BitMatrix bitMatrix = multiFormatWriter.encode(total_text, BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE,200,200);
            BarcodeEncoder barcodeEncoder = new BarcodeEncoder();
            Bitmap bitmap = barcodeEncoder.createBitmap(bitMatrix);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        } catch (WriterException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

After I build the project,gradle6.5-all.zip was downloaded. But I did not find it under /AndroidStudioProjects/SWULJ.City.Conductor3/gradle/wrapper/ folder
So, I created a folder "dists" under this folder. Downloaded gradle6.5-all.zip separately into Download folder and copied into "dists" folder.
But I get error, error: cannot find symbol  MultiFormatWriter, BitMatrix, BarcodeEncoder, WriterException
Generally when I find such errors, I hover my mouse over the symbol, then import option shows and I import headers
But in this case import option is not showing
Am I doing some mistake? Have I missed something?
I searched for the folder gradle-6.5, in the system.
It is present in locations
/home/user/AndroidStudioProjects/SWULJ.City.Conductor3/gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-6.5-all.zip
/home/user/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-6.5-all/2oz4ud9k3tuxjg84bbf55q0tn/gradle-6.5-all.zip
/home/user/Downloads/gradle-6.5-all.zip

Answer (score 0):

changed

```
implementation 'com.google.zxing:core:3.2.1'
    implementation 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.2.0@aar'
```

to

```
compile 'com.google.zxing:core:3.2.1'
    compile 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.2.0@aar'
```

Then sync option came. clicked "sync now" and build the project, then things were fine.
I guess sync fixed the issue

Answer (score 0):

I used this code for generating QR code,

**Dependency**

```
implementation 'com.google.zxing:core:3.5.1'
```

**Java**

```
private Bitmap qrCodeGenerator(String text){
    QRCodeWriter writer = new QRCodeWriter();
    try {
        BitMatrix bitMatrix = writer.encode(text, BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE, 512, 512);
        int width = bitMatrix.getWidth();
        int height = bitMatrix.getHeight();
        Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
                bmp.setPixel(x, y, bitMatrix.get(x, y) ? Color.BLACK : Color.WHITE);
            }
        }
        return bmp;
    }catch (WriterException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```